# Android: How to access the other elements of parent list item on click of image view

Tags: android, listview, imageview, listadapter, listitem

I have a `ListView` with custom list items each containing an `ImageView` on the left and 3 more imageviews-tick,cross,undo images. I want to change the image of the `ImageView` on the left when I click on the tick or cross or undo buttons.I tried storing a reference of the listview in the adapter and used

```
 ImageView imgReturn = (ImageView)lstViewAppr.getChildAt(index).findViewById(R.id.imgPerson)
```

But `getChildAt(int)` returns null for some list items. Any suggestions ?

Comment: In your code, what is index?

Comment: holder.imgAppr.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
ImageView imgAppr = (ImageView) v;
final int index = (Integer) imgAppr.getTag();
COAAppr objCoa = CoaApprList.get(index);
ImageView imgPeople = (ImageView) lstViewAppr.getChildAt(index)
.findViewById(R.id.imgPeople);
if (objCoa.getSTATUSTEMP().equals("Approve")) {
objCoa.setSTATUSTEMP("");
imgAppr.setImageDrawable(c.getResources().getDrawable(
R.drawable.ic_action_tick));
imgPeople.setImageDrawable(c.getResources().getDrawable(
R.drawable.ic_action_checked));}}});

Comment: i am storing the index as a tag in the imageview in the adapter

Comment: Change this line : `ImageView imgReturn = (ImageView)lstViewAppr.getChildAt(index).findViewById(R.id.imgPerson)`
 to : `ImageView imgReturn = (ImageView)lstViewAppr.findViewById(R.id.imgPerson);`

Comment: Please add both the code where you set the index and this code to the question itself.